# Swiper js performing functions while slider is moving

Tags: javascript, events, swiper.js

I'm having problem when executing functions in swiper.js.

I need to achieve the effect that the setImagePositions() function will execute from the moment I grab the slide and move it until the slider is fully stopped.

At the moment it only executes when it grabs and moves.

I've added more function code that I want to call all the time from the moment I start dragging until the slider stops.

```js
let parallaxAmount = 49;
let verticalAmount = 60;
let rotationAmount = 6;

let swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  slidesPerView: 4,
  centeredSlides: true,
  spaceBetween: 20,
  freeMode: {
    enabled: true,
  },
});

function setImagePositions() {

  $(".swiper-slide").each(function (index) {
    let targetElement = $(this);

    let elementOffsetLeft =
      targetElement.offset().left +
      targetElement.width() -
      $('.swiper').offset().left;
    let progressLeft =
      elementOffsetLeft / ($('.swiper').width() + targetElement.width());

    let elementOffsetCenter =
      targetElement.offset().left +
      targetElement.width() / 2 -
      $('.swiper').width() / 2;
    let parentWidth = $('.swiper').width() + targetElement.width();
    let progressCenter = elementOffsetCenter / parentWidth;

    let progressCenterInvert = progressCenter;
    if (progressCenterInvert < 0) {
      progressCenterInvert = progressCenterInvert * -1;
    }

    let imageMoveDistance = parallaxAmount * progressLeft;
    if (imageMoveDistance > parallaxAmount) {
      imageMoveDistance = parallaxAmount;
    } else if (imageMoveDistance < 0) {
      imageMoveDistance = 0;
    }
    

    targetElement
      .find(".swiper-slider-inner")
      .css(
        "transform",
        `translateY(${verticalAmount * progressCenter}%) rotate(${rotationAmount * progressCenter
        }deg)`
      );

  });

}
swiper.on('setTranslate', function () {
  setImagePositions();
});
```

```css
body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slider-inner {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>1</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>2</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>3</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>4</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>5</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>6</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>7</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>8</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>9</span></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you could create similar functionality using the `slideChangeTransitionStart` and `slideChangeTransitionEnd` events - start an interval when it starts, make the callback for that do whatever you need to do - and cancel the interval again on end?

Comment: I tried this way to start the functions in the 1ms interval, and at the End I turn off the interval. Unfortunately, this solution causes my photos to jump minimally.

Comment: What do you actually need to _achieve_ by this?

Comment: @CBroe I add some code to the example with what I want to achieve. If you grab and pull the slide, it's ok - because the function is working. But once you catch and unclick, it's not smooth anymore.

Answer (score 0):

So SwipperJS doesn't have an event that you can listen to when you enable freemove. So the only way to handle this would be to use setInterval for a time to update the images and then clearInterval to remove it after that period of time.

You can determine the smoothness you want by running the code more times per second. So you would want to change the setInverval to a smaller number. Also you could adjust how many times it should run before stopping. In this case you would want to adjust the maxLoop count to a higher number.

```js
let parallaxAmount = 49;
let verticalAmount = 60;
let rotationAmount = 6;

// Track Interval ID
let freeMoveInterval = null;

let swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  slidesPerView: 4,
  centeredSlides: true,
  spaceBetween: 20,
  freeMode: {
    enabled: true,
  },
});

function setImagePositions() {

  $(".swiper-slide").each(function (index) {
    let targetElement = $(this);

    let elementOffsetLeft =
      targetElement.offset().left +
      targetElement.width() -
      $('.swiper').offset().left;
    let progressLeft =
      elementOffsetLeft / ($('.swiper').width() + targetElement.width());

    let elementOffsetCenter =
      targetElement.offset().left +
      targetElement.width() / 2 -
      $('.swiper').width() / 2;
    let parentWidth = $('.swiper').width() + targetElement.width();
    let progressCenter = elementOffsetCenter / parentWidth;

    let progressCenterInvert = progressCenter;
    if (progressCenterInvert < 0) {
      progressCenterInvert = progressCenterInvert * -1;
    }

    let imageMoveDistance = parallaxAmount * progressLeft;
    if (imageMoveDistance > parallaxAmount) {
      imageMoveDistance = parallaxAmount;
    } else if (imageMoveDistance < 0) {
      imageMoveDistance = 0;
    }
    

    targetElement
      .find(".swiper-slider-inner")
      .css(
        "transform",
        `translateY(${verticalAmount * progressCenter}%) rotate(${rotationAmount * progressCenter
        }deg)`
      );

  });

}

swiper.on('setTranslate', function () {
    // Clear Interval before setting it again
    if ( freeMoveInterval ) clearInterval( freeMoveInterval );

    let count = 0;
    let maxLoop = 300;

    // Create an interval to handle freemove
    freeMoveInterval = setInterval(() => {
        // Check the loop count and exit on max count
        if ( count++ > maxLoop ){
            clearInterval( freeMoveInterval );
            freeMoveInterval = null;
            return null;
        }
        // Run the code
        setImagePositions();
    }, 10 );
});

// Set Image positions on page load
setImagePositions();
```

```css
body {
    background: #eee;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slider-inner {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>1</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>2</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>3</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>4</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>5</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>6</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>7</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>8</span></div></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-slider-inner"><span>9</span></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution - it works but there is a jumping problem if you hold the slider and move it you can see that it is not smooth. I have a problem here too.

Comment: You can make it smoother by changing maxLoop to a higher number and setInterval to a lower number. For example: `let maxLoop = 300;` and `setInterval(() => { ... }, 10);`